# How can I extract that number from string?

Tags: python, regex, string-matching

in the string instances like:

```
A Dirty Shame (2004)
```

I have date at the end. I would like to extract that date as a number to another variable. How would I solve this in python?

There can be a number at the name as well!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re
s = 'A Dirty Shame (2004)'
pattern = r'(?P<year>\d{4})'
r = re.search(pattern, s)
n = int(r.group('year'))
```

Only looks for 4 digit numbers. Converts the string to integer.

Comment: +1 for named group. What should happen after year 9999?

Comment: What will come after year 9999? 0000?

Comment: r won't work in the last line unless you change the second to last line to r = re.search(pattern, s)

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
re.findall('\d+', 'A Dirty Shame (2004)')
```

Comment: what if there is a number at the begining of the name

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
import re
number = int(re.findall('(?<=\()\d+(?=\))', 'A Dirty Shame (2004)')[0]);
```

Or you can use the following which will find all digits between parentheses wherever they are in the string without using regex:

```
[int(s.strip('()')) for s in s.split() if s.strip('()').isdigit()]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another answer, but without using regex (as they are usually slow):

I would use the split funktion from string, which splits the string at a seperator ( http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split ) as you got two distinctive seperators (the '(' and the ')')

```
>>> import string
>>> A = "A Dirty Shame (2004)"
>>> B = A.split('(')[1].split(')')[0]
>>> B
'2004'
```

Be aware that this will not work if any other parentheses are existing in the string

Answer (score 0):

Find everything inside the brackets:

```
import re
re.findall('\((.*)\)', 'A Dirty Shame (2004)')[0]
```

This regex will continue to work if the title also includes numerals eg 'Back to the Future 3 (1986)')

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`re.search`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "A Dirty Shame (2004)"
>>> myresult =  int(re.search(r'\((.*?)\)', s).group(1))
>>> print myresult
2004
```

`.*?` captures all items inside the adjacent tokens. In this case, it gets everything between the parentheses. `\(` matches the first open parenthesis. We have to escape it (by putting a backslash) because the parenthesis is already something else in regex - the grouping token, which we use to get everything between the brackets. We then do the opposite on the other side.

`re.search()` returns a match if the regular expression matches anything in the string. As it has done so, we call `.group(1)` on the end to obtain the year, 2004.

Finally, we enclose `int()` around it to convert the string `"2004"` to an integer `2004`.